# Node.js htaccess like get rules

Tags: node.js

I am looking for a way to set dynamic url http://host.com/dynamic_value-123/  and be able to get these values (123)

Comment: What do you mean by 'set dynamic url' ?

Comment: all get('/*.*') will do the trick in my case , but I guess I cannot set "*.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have the most basic example of a server with Node.js, you can achieve that with `req.url.split('-')[1]`:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.url.split('-')[1]);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```